# Cell fracture messes up texture UV, doesn't apply material to interior, doesn't take fracture count limit into account

Tags: uv

Cell fracture messes up texture UV, doesn't apply material to interior, doesn't take fracture count limit into account. (makes 12-20 cells no matter what value I set)

I really need fracturing for my game and I've been struggling with this for the past two days.

Is there a version of blender where cell fracturing works properly? I have tried 5 of them.

Comment: There are lot of possible reason that could cause these problems.Could you provide a screenshot, or a blend file so we can try to better understand the situation? What is the point source generator? Own verts, child verts, own particles....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a year late, but I literally made an account here so I can answer this question! I've been beating my head against a wall for the last 3 days and I finally got it to work.

So, I was using cell fracture in blender 2.77. It looked great, fractured wonderfully, and completely ruined my UVs.

I found out that Blender 2.64 was a working version of cell fracture, downloaded it and imported my .blend file (of the unshattered object) into it. When I shattered it, everything was perfect.

I don't know what you're doing with the cell fracture, but I imported it into Unity, and (warning in case that's what you're doing) I got very odd extra materials.

To fix this, I exported the shattered cube from 2.64 as an fbx, opened it in 2.77, re-exported it as an fbx, and when I put it into unity I had no extra materials.

This can not be the only way to make it work, but here's the convoluted path I took.

I really hope this helps you or you found another fix. I understand your frustration.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same 'UV-mess-up' issue with the cell fracture addon (2.79). I tried other versions of Blender (2.64 and 2.74), but it gave the same problem. Then I learned that when you enable *Debug Boolean* in the cell fracture options, the UV's are totally fine!

Now the *Debug Boolean* option gives each separate chunk a boolean modifier. To apply the modifiers, simply select all the chunks, then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to convert to mesh.

The only problem is that some chunks don't show up, after applying the cell fracture. But to fix that, before you convert the chunks to a mesh, select the chunks that aren't showing, go to the boolean modifier, and where it says *BMesh*, click and select *Carve*, and they show up again.

With the other problems I have not much experience, all I can say is to try different Point Source methods (I find particles to be a useful way).

Comment: great! works perfect for me!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (2.76b).  After fracturing a uv mapped object, the textures ended up low res on the fractured object.  I had to rejoin the fractured objects into a single object and unwrap the object again.  After unwrapping and tweaking the uv-s a bit, I selected the entire mesh and separated by loose parts.  Basically, you use cell fracture to "fracture" the original mesh, rejoin the shards and re-map the uvs, then make each loose part its own object again.

Comment: I had no luck with this (2.79). When separating by loose parts, many shards would not form correctly: Their back faces would become parts of their own and the front and all side (i.e., fracturing) faces another non-manifold object.